# How to convert list of Tuples from a dataframe column to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below, with a column having list of tuples

```
Task Area
1    [(area1, area2), (area3, area4)]
2    [(area3, area4), (area6, arae5), (area8, area10)]
3    [(area2, area4)]
```

how to separate the area column to two different columns, like shown below

```
Task Area_a Area_b
1    area1  area2
1    area3  area4
2    area3  area4
2    area6  area5
2    area8  area10
3    area2  area4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and create the dataframe anew:

```
exp =  df['Task Area'].explode()
df = pd.DataFrame(exp.values.tolist(), 
                  columns=['Area_a', 'Area_b'],
                  index=exp.index)

df.rename_axis('Task').reset_index()

   Task Area_a  Area_b
0     1  area1   area2
1     1  area3   area4
2     2  area3   area4
3     2  area6   arae5
4     2  area8  area10
5     3  area2   area4
```